# Physical Vs Logical delete of file stored as BLOB from Database

Tags: mysql, grails, blob, grails-orm, sql-delete

I have app in `grails(uses GORM -  grails ORM)` and DB is `MySql`. I have table called 'attachment' in database which stores the files attached in web app as `blob type`. Each file size varies from 30 kb - 200 kb. Now I want to provide a provision for users to delete the attachments. The entries `deleted will not be re-used` and i don't have unique constraint on any fields.

total size of table `attachment` is  `35 MB`. Which keeps growing.

And there is a relationship between the table 'attachment' and table 'training'. which says training has got many attachments.

**1) Is it good idea to use logical delete (deleted =  true) against the physical delete ?.**

**2) Does logical delete affects the performance of DB (keeping the rows in the table without deleting them especially BLOB type) ?.**

Comment: logical delete is a bad idea. the data remains in db means its affects the performance of db. "The entries deleted will not be re-used" => means better you delete the records form the table.

Comment: A logical delete is good if you NEED to keep the data for one reason or another, but want to give your users the option of removing the file from their view. If you don't need to keep the files, delete the record.

Comment: Yes, The rows i want to delete is NOT NEEDED for future use, So By doing the physical delete the row will deleted and id as well, Finally we will be not having sequential id's. will that be problem